Calculate point coords relative to a rotated DIV
I have a rotated DIV within a non-rotated DIV and I'm trying to work out the cursor position on the outer DIV in relation to the rotated DIV. I guess I need the position as though the coordinate system has been rotated to match the angle of the rotated div.
Following is an example of what I need:

I know or can easily get:

w1, the width of the outer DIV
h1, the height of the outer DIV
w2, the width of the inner/rotated DIV
h2, the height of the inner/rotated DIV
a, the angle of the rotated DIV
x1, the x coord of a point P
y1, the y coord of a point P

I don't know how to get, but need, x2 and y2.

I made a mistake :-(  y2 should be from P to the top corner (the corner touching the top edge of the outer DIV.)

Please visit [ask] - if you post a [mcve] it is easier to help

Please then [edit] your post to correct your expected output and, as @ㅤmplungjan says, add a [mre].

I ignore whether you can access that information using built-in tools, so here is a possible answer that centres on the maths of the problem.
What you're doing is basically an affine transformation, specifically the composition of a translation and a rotation:

Where the rotation matrix is:

; and the translation vector is:

So, in fine, the coordinates in the new system should be:
let x2 = x1*Math.cos(a) + Math.sin(a) * (-y1 + w2*Math.sin(a));
let y2 = y1*Math.cos(a) + Math.sin(a) * (+x1 - w2*Math.cos(a));

EDIT - The previous solution deals with the original posted problem; to tackle the "new" modified version - as described by the OP in the comments -, there are two possibilities:

either to simply apply to the above result the transformation (x, y) --> (x, h2-y) (this is the easy way);
or to re-formalise the problem from scratch. We'll now do this for didactic reasons.

In this second scenario, apart from the aforementioned rotation and translation, the affine transformation includes a reflection about the x axis, and an additional translation:

; where the rotation matrix is still:

; the reflection can be written:

; the first translation, as before, is:

; and, finally, the second translation vector:

Inverting the system, the final result is:
let x2 = +x1*Math.cos(a) + Math.sin(a) * (-y1 + w2*Math.sin(a));
let y2 = -y1*Math.cos(a) + Math.sin(a) * (-x1 + w2*Math.cos(a)) + h2;


When I put some values into x2 and y2 - (100, 0) at 0.8 radians within a 300px square DIV - for, say, the top corner it gives
100 * Math.cos(0.8) + Math.sin(0.8) * (-0 + 300 * Math.sin(0.8))
which is 224 and not the 0 as I would expect.  And y2 equals
0 * Math.cos(0.8) + Math.sin(0.8) * (+100 - 300 * Math.cos(0.8));
which is -78 and not 0. What am I missing/not understanding?

How is (100, 0) the top corner? The top corner of the inner, square div, with w2 = 300 and a = PI/4 ~ 0.8, would be (x1, y1) = (300/sqrt(2), 300*sqrt(2)). And the formula yields (x2, y2) = (0, 300).

With the same configuration, the left corner of the inner div, corresponding to (x1, y1) = (0, 300/sqrt(2)), transforms to (x2, y2) = (0, 0).

Oh no, I'm sorry I did something stupid (I took more care drawing a nice sketch than a correct one.) I drew the sketch incorrectly. y2 should be from P to the corner that touches the top edge of the outer DIV (not the left hand side edge.)
